# How to fix this Gradle task dependency problem?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

## Summary

I have a multiproject Gradle build consisting of multiple Java application subprojects and a base Java library subproject that each application references as a dependency. It should be possible to produce a Jar file for each application containing all of it's class files and those of its dependencies (aka fatJar) which is executed during the `build` lifecycle.

## Problem

Ideally I would just override the default Jar task so that it behaves like a "fatJar" by also including the dependencies files from the runtimeClasspath like this:

```
jar {
  manifest.attributes 'Main-Class': application.mainClass
  archiveBaseName = "${rootProject.name}-${project.name}"
  duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
  from configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect{it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
}
```

But this throws a Gradle error:

```
Task ':app1:jar' uses this output of task ':app-base:jar' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency.

Possible solutions:
      1. Declare task ':app-base:jar' as an input of ':controlling-sim:jar'.
      2. Declare an explicit dependency on ':app-base:jar' from ':controlling-sim:jar' using Task#dependsOn.
      3. Declare an explicit dependency on ':app-base:jar' from ':controlling-sim:jar' using Task#mustRunAfter.
```

I don't understand why this exists even with the error explanation and guidance. It doesn't make sense having to declare an explicit dependency between tasks of different projects.

An alternative is to register a new Jar-type task called `fatJar` but trying to make this execute during the `build` lifecycle causes it to throw the same error as above, if I do:

`buildSrc/src/main/groovy/application-conventions.gradle`

```
tasks.assemble.dependsOn fatJar
```

Without the above dependency, the fatJar task works fine but it requires the user to run the `fatJar` task manually.

- How do I avoid the error above?

Full project structure:

#### `buildSrc/src/main/groovy/base-conventions.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

#### `buildSrc/src/main/groovy/application-conventions.gradle`

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'application'
}

repositories {
  mavenLocal()
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':app-base')
}

jar {
  manifest.attributes 'Main-Class': application.mainClass
  archiveBaseName = "${rootProject.name}-${project.name}"
  duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
  from configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect{it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
}

// Alternative...
/*tasks.register('fatJar', Jar) {
  manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': application.mainClass
  }
  group = 'build'
  archiveBaseName = "${rootProject.name}-${project.name}"
  duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
  from configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect{it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
}*/
```

#### `app-base/build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'base-conventions'
}

dependencies {
  api 'com.xyz:lib-java:1.0'
  implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.3.14'
}
```

#### `app1/build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'application-conventions'
}

application {
    mainClass = 'com.xyz.app1.Main'
}
```

## What have I tried?

Explicitly adding a dependency between the tasks seems to work but doesn't seem like the correct approach:

```
jar {
dependsOn project(":app-base").tasks.jar
}
```

Adding a dependency between the assemble task and my task:

```
tasks.assemble.dependsOn fatJar
```

Comment: why don't you use the shadow jar plugin?

Comment: I tried briefly but had other issues. My other reasons are, I want to learn how to do this myself and don't need the other features the Shadow Jar plugin provides.

Comment: you don't need other features NOW :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradle is warning that the jar task now uses files that may be generated by something else without having a dependency on them. The "Possible solutions" message about how to fix it is not so helpful in this case though.

As an example, if this is a multi-project and a subproject is declared as a dependency for the runtimeOnly configuration (e.g. `runtimeOnly project('something')`, then the standard jar task would not pick it up as it by default only knows cares about the output of this task, thus skipping the subproject. Another example would be a runtime dependency that has not been downloaded yet - if the task doesn't have a dependency on it, it will also be skipped.

To fix it, add a dependency to the configuration in use like this:

```
jar {
  manifest.attributes 'Main-Class': application.mainClass
  archiveBaseName = "${rootProject.name}-${project.name}"
  duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
  dependsOn configurations.runtimeClasspath // <-- This
  from configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect{it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
}
```

And if you choose to create a new fatJar task entirely, you will also need a `from sourceSets.main.output` to include the project classes. (This implicitly adds a dependency to the compile task.)

Comment: Not supposed to say thanks here but, thank you. That worked perfectly!
It seems so simple and logical now you've explained but I would have expected simply by referencing the `runtimeClasspath` configuration it would create an implicit dependency. Not sure why using `dependsOn configurations.runtimeClasspath` makes a difference but I will research further.
I tried both overriding the jar task and using a fatJar task. Both work really well but I have gone with just the jar task as it's cleaner. Thanks again!